# Understanding an answer, finding the probabity of $x\in[0,1]$ being less than $\frac13$

Tags: probability

Let $E$ be “the choosing of a number on the interval $[0, 1]$ such that the
number is less than $1/3$. In this case, the use of the definition is a bit more
subtle but essentially it gives

$$\mathbb P(E)= \dfrac{\text{Length of } [0, 1/3)}{\text{Length of }[0,1]}$$

Here is the image of the interval:

[image]

Comment: Essentially it is just saying that if you pick a number randomly (such that is equally likely any number in the interval $[0,1]$ is chosen), then the probability of picking a number in the interval $[0,1/3]$ is just the length of that interval divided by the length of $[0,1]$, (that is, $1/3$).

Comment: @John: They got the answer, it seems, by using a certain definition. Without that definition, one cannot give more detail. Presumably they are discussing the uniform distribution over an interval.

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I'll present a non-rigorous but intuitive way to think about this.

Consider "discretizing": Take the interval $[0,1]$ and break it into $N$ pieces of equal length: $[0,\frac1N),[\frac1N,\frac2N),\ldots [\frac{N-1}N,1]$. Rather than selecting a number, just select one of the $N$ pieces. So we can understand that "equally likely" means each piece has a probability of $\frac 1 N$ of being selected.

You can interpret the probability of the sub-interval $[0,\frac13)$ as being the probability your chosen interval will be a subset of $[0,1/3)$. Since we have $N$ sub-intervals of that are of equal length, you should intuitively see that approximately one third of them are subsets of $[0,1/3)$. If $N$ is a multiple of three, then it is exactly one third of them.

$$\mathbb P([0,1/3)) \approx \frac{\frac13\times N}{ N}=\frac13$$

Similarly, you might now see that the number of tiny sub-intervals that fall inside interval $(a,b)$ (a subset of $[0,1]$) is approximately the length of interval $(a,b)$.

You will also see a similar idea in 2D and higher dimensions. Consider a large target dart board with a smaller circle in the center (the bullseye). If you randomly throw a dart at the dart board -- and assume the dart will land at each point on the board with equal likelihood -- then the probability of "hitting the bullseye" is the area of the bullseye circle divided by the total area of the dart board. Similarly you could break the dartboard into small regions of equal area and count how many fall inside the bullseye and divide by the total number.

This is not a precise/rigorous argument, but hopefully it provides a different way to think about probability as a ratio of lengths or areas.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you pick a number between 0 and 1 unfiformly.

Let X be the random variable of choosing a number between $0$ and $n$. And $X$ is uniformly distributed. First we apply the [Bayes rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_rule).

$P(X\leq 1/3|X < n)=\frac{P(X\leq 1/3\cap X\leq n)}{P(X< n)}$

For $n=1$ we get

$P(X\leq 1/3|X < 1)=\frac{P(X\leq 1/3)}{P(X< 1)}$

The cdf of a uniform distributed random variable on $[0,1]$ is

$F(x)=\begin{cases}0, x <0 \\ x, 0\leq x < 1 \\ 1, \geq 1 \end{cases}$

Thus $P(X\leq 1/3)=\frac13$ and $P(X< 1)=1$ and $P(X\leq 1/3|X <1)=\frac{\frac13}{1}=\frac13$